# Get a last job result for other pipeline jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I need to create a Jenkins pipeline that fetches the result of a specific job and displays it within the pipeline along with the data. This would be a pipeline that checks the outcomes of other pipelines.

I took this example from the documentation, but when I try to adapt it to the built-in Jenkins REST API, it can't find the path.

`def response = httpRequest 'http://localhost:8080/jenkins/api/json?pretty=true' println("Status: "+response.status) println("Content: "+response.content)`

my test :

`def response = httpRequest 'http://jenkins:PORT/jenkins/job/jobName/api/json?pretty=true' println("Status: "+response.status) println("Content: "+response.content)`

I believe I need to provide credentials because I'm receiving a 403 error. However, I'm not sure how to set them up.

um código que eu possa usar.